# .htaccess stop removing index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am having trouble after switching a customers site over to my linux cpanel webserver

accessing the site does work but the links do not,

I need it to stop it removing index.php after the domain name on all of the links (or start adding it!)

This is currently my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can anybody tell me how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]` - then test it

Comment: removed it, now I just get 404 whenever i click a link

Comment: Try this: RewriteRule . index.php [L]

Comment: Try changing `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Smokey you are a legend! all working now 
Thanks

Comment: @user2195891 Glad to have helped, please accept my answer below by clicking on the tick icon under the vote arrows, to make it clear that this question is resolved (and how)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [R=301,L]
```